# Delete first and last character from from each line of a txt file

Tags: shell, unix

I need to delete the first and the last character from the each line of a text file.

for example:

Input

```
$cat file1.txt
|head1|head2|head3|
|1|2|3|
|2|3|4|
```

Output:

```
head1|head2|head3
1|2|3
2|3|4
```

Comment: does it always end with a pipe?

Comment: |MRC Code|Product           |Bravo Minor|Period|Current Year|Version|Country Code|G/L Accoun|Net Units Sold - Per Anum|MU|Sales Amount - Per Anum|Net Units Sold - Per Month|Sales Amount - Per Month|Sales Currency|ICP Flag|Upload id|
|    1757|02.100.004        |      47830|   10 |2016        |0      |PR          |60515900  |                   1.000 |EA|                  0.00 |                    0.000 |                   0.00 |              |Y       | 157282 |

Comment: I have added the sample data above

Comment: [Edit] your question to show us the sample data, rather than posting it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/.$//; s/^.//' inputfile
```

Comment: This command is removing the first '|' only. Not the last one

Comment: |MRC Code|Product           |Bravo Minor|Period|Current Year|Version|Country Code|G/L Accoun|Net Units Sold - Per Anum|MU|Sales Amount - Per Anum|Net Units Sold - Per Month|Sales Amount - Per Month|Sales Currency|ICP Flag|Upload id|
|    1757|02.100.004        |      47830|   10 |2016        |0      |PR          |60515900  |                   1.000 |EA|                  0.00 |                    0.000 |                   0.00 |              |Y       | 157282 |

Comment: Added the sample data

Comment: echo "|head1|head2|head3|" | sed 's/.$//; s/^./
head1|head2|head3    worked when i tested it.

Comment: `echo "|head1|head2|head3|" | sed 's/.$//; s/^.//'` works for me. I think my answer is valid

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it in one sed command:

```
sed -E 's/^.|.$//g' file
```

Match a character at the start or the end of the line and replace with nothing.

In basic mode, remember that the `|` needs to be escaped:

```
sed 's/^.\|.$//g' file
```

Comment: This command is removing the first '|' only. Not the last one

Comment: |MRC Code|Product           |Bravo Minor|Period|Current Year|Version|Country Code|G/L Accoun|Net Units Sold - Per Anum|MU|Sales Amount - Per Anum|Net Units Sold - Per Month|Sales Amount - Per Month|Sales Currency|ICP Flag|Upload id|
|    1757|02.100.004        |      47830|   10 |2016        |0      |PR          |60515900  |                   1.000 |EA|                  0.00 |                    0.000 |                   0.00 |              |Y       | 157282 |

Comment: added the smaple data

Comment: @smisra3: Command seems to be nice. Does your input line end with a space?

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is helpful:

```
awk '{print substr($0,2,length($0)-2)}' file
head1|head2|head3
1|2|3
2|3|4
```

Answer (score 0):

@smisra- Could you please try following, it may help you in same too.

```
awk '{gsub(/^\||\|$/,X,$0);print}'  Input_file
```